# php class to combine css and js files before load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, minify

I am looking for a way to combine external css files , and even inline css codes with `php` , before load html , and then add them into a external file with all css codes in page .

I want to add this ability for `js` files too .

currently I have a minify html function which delete spaces and new lines from html .

```
function _minify_html($input) {
    return preg_replace_callback('#<\s*([^\/\s]+)\s*(?:>|(\s[^<>]+?)\s*>)#', function($m) {
        if(isset($m[2])) {

            return '<' . $m[1] . preg_replace(
                array(
                    // From `defer="defer"`, `defer='defer'`, `defer="true"`, `defer='true'`, `defer=""` and `defer=''` to `defer` [^1]
                    '#\s(checked|selected|async|autofocus|autoplay|controls|defer|disabled|hidden|ismap|loop|multiple|open|readonly|required|scoped)(?:=([\'"]?)(?:true|\1)?\2)#i',
                    // Remove extra white-space(s) between HTML attribute(s) [^2]
                    '#\s*([^\s=]+?)(=(?:\S+|([\'"]?).*?\3)|$)#',
                    // From `<img />` to `<img/>` [^3]
                    '#\s+\/$#'
                ),
                array(
                    // [^1]
                    ' $1',
                    // [^2]
                    ' $1$2',
                    // [^3]
                    '/'
                ),
            str_replace("\n", ' ', $m[2])) . '>';
        }
        return '<' . $m[1] . '>';
    }, $input);
}


function minifyHtml($buffer) {
    $buffer = _minify_html($buffer);
    return 
        // remove ws outside of all elements
        preg_replace( '/>(?:\s\s*)?([^<]+)(?:\s\s*)?</s', '>$1<', 
            // remove ws around all elems excepting script|style|pre|textarea elems
            preg_replace(
            '/\s+(<\\/?(?!script|style|pre|textarea)\b[^>]*>)/i', '$1',
                // trim line start
                preg_replace( '/^\s\s*/m', '', 
                    // trim line end
                    preg_replace( '/\s\s*$/m', '', 
                        // remove HTML comments (not containing IE conditional comments)
                        preg_replace_callback( 
                            '/<!--[^ShowThitComment]([\s\S]*?)-->/', 
                            function( $m ) {
                                return ( 0 === strpos($m[1], '[' ) || false !== strpos( $m[1], '<![' ) ) ? $m[0] : '';
                            },
                            // start point
                            $buffer 
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ;
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You would achieve what you want more efficiently using Gulp. Look at [gulp-clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css) for minifying css and [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) for minifying js.

To get started with gulp [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js) is a good place.

Comment: You can also check also: http://gruntjs.com/
It works with watch, less and uglify. You can configure the enviroment to compile everything when you save a file.